# my Download speed

Tags: download

I connect via a cell phone. It indicates speed as 921.6 Kbps. When I download a program or other it shows a download speed of 3 - 5 Kbps while downloading.  Can I increase my download speed or is it governed by the cell phone.

Comment: It should be 3-5 KBps and not Kbps.

Answer (score 4):

Download speeds are mainly governed by the type of network connection you have.

However, first, you should know the difference between `Kbps` and `KBps`.

- `Kbps` - stands for `Kilo bits per second`
- `KBps` - stands for `Kilo Bytes per second`

```
1 KBps = 8 Kbps
```

Also, you might know that `1 MB = 1024 KB (and not 1024 Kb)`.

So, here you're getting a speed of 921.6 Kbps which is approximately equal to 115.2 KBps.

The download speed, however, depends on a number of factors which cannot be summarised here.

The simplest thing would be to download when no other process is using the internet.